# How to deploy SWF file to Websphere application server?

Tags: apache-flex, websphere, flash

I want to deploy my application coded in FLEX to my WAS 7.0.0.4 on localhost. The application is exported as a SWF file. But I don't have got any experience with WAS and I didn't find any tutorial how to do that and that whole system looks really confuzing to me. Could somebody write step-by-step solution or give me any advice how to reach my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd probably be better off just using an HTTP server like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [IBM HTTP Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/) (which is much the same thing). It sounds like you're deploying static content (from the server's perspective), so an application server will only add complexity and use more resources without providing you with any additional functionality. On an HTTP server, all you need to do is place the files you want to deliver to the browser in a specific directory.

Comment: However, if you really want to use WebSphere Application Server, you will need to package your static content in a JavaEE enterprise application (EAR file) and deploy this to the server.

Comment: I need to deploy it to WAS, because we use it in my job. As you've said, the solution was to use maven, to build the project and it also creates EAR, which I could deploy to WAS :)